# Meta tag is not getting update in Angular 6

Tags: angular, meta-tags

I am using ng2-Meta in Angular 6. I have set default meta tag in `index.html` file. What I want to achieve is that by clicking on share button whatever I set in title and description that should be updated in meta tag and value should be shared on particular share medium.

Here is my index.html code:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="web site name" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="site name" />
<meta property="og:image" content="site logo" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="web site name" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="19289---1301817" />
<meta property="og:description" id="description" content="Great mental health experience starts with MindCentral. Join us on a mission to better the world and ourselves." />
<meta name="description" id="description" content="Great mental health experience starts with MindCentral. Join us on a mission to better the world and ourselves." />
```

On function click in ts file:

```js
this.titleService.setTitle('web site name');
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'I just received this '+ awardName +' Award on MindCentral! Join me to become better therapist.' })
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:title', content: 'Mind Central' })
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:description', content: 'I just received this '+ awardName +' Award on MindCentral! Join me to become better therapist.' })
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:image', content: 'image url' })
```

It is always showing me the description which I set in index.html file not which I am updating.

Here is my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7m2j1

I clear my browser history too. But it wasn't affected.